# nasm macro language: check if the parameter is not numeric

Tags: macros, nasm

We have a command `%ifnum` in macro language:

> %ifnum tests for the token being an integer numeric constant (not an
> expression!) possibly preceded by + or -;

I need to check the opposite: if the parameter is not a number or it is less then 1, then throw an error:

```
%macro my_macro 1
    ;%if_not_num %1 || %1 < 1 <- ?
    %if %1 < 1
        %error "Parameter 1 must be >= 1"
    %endif
%endmacro
```

How to write `%if_not_num %1`?

Comment: `%ifnnum %1` \ `%warning not num` \ `%elif %1 < 1` \ `%warning below 1` \ `%else` \ `%warning above-or-equal 1` \ `%endif` -- Note you cannot check for not number and a numeric value in the same expression, not even [with the new `%isnum(%1)` expression](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.4.5), because the expression would contain an invalid parameter if it is not a number. Hence my use of an `%elif` branch.

Comment: To more specifically reply to your question: [The manual says](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.16.01/html/nasmdoc4.html#section-4.6.6): "The usual %elif..., %ifn..., and %elifn... versions exist for each of %ifid, %ifnum and %ifstr."